# Phonegap Immersify mode stops after opening android keyboard

Tags: android, cordova

i'm making an android app based on phonegap and cordova and trying to configure immersify mode so that it would work at all times. Current script runs when the app just opened or resumed. The problem is that this app requires to fill some textfields, but each time you call out android keyboard the immersive mode will stop working and won't be called back on. Using the given phonegaps event list i have no idea how to work around it. One way would be binding every button pressed in app to call out function again, but it seems silly to call out this function over and over again where it's not necessary.

```
window.ImmersiveMode = {
initialize: function()
  {
     this.bindEvents();
     console.log("Immersify is running");
  },
  // Bind Event Listeners
 bindEvents: function()
  {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
      document.addEventListener('resume', this.onResume,false);
      document.addEventListener('pause', this.onPause, false);
  },
 onDeviceReady: function()
  {
Immersify.enableSticky();
  },
onResume: function()
{
Immersify.enableSticky();
},
onPause: function()
{
Immersify.disable();
},
};

ImmersiveMode.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same problem and i think i have bad news for you. I've done some research and there' s a bug with the fullscreen mode. When it's on the hidekeyboard and showkeyboard events are not triggered. Only when the fullscreen mode is off. Check this link to understand better the bug:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-392

If you want to know this are the events:

document.addEventListener('hidekeyboard', this.onKeyboardHide, false);
document.addEventListener('showkeyboard', this.onKeyboardHide, false);

Sorry for the bad news! :/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Using the [ionic-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) will trigger those events even when immersive mode (Fullscreen) is active.

So, install that plugin and use it like this:

`window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', event => { console.log(event); });`